# List of completely deployed application on jboss

Tags: deployment, jboss, jboss5.x, twiddle

I have 2-3 application(of type war and ear) deployed on jboss 5.0.1 GA.Actually i need a way to check the list of completely deployed applications without opening the actual application.There is a way to see that by using :-

> twiddle.sh query 'jboss.web.deployment:*

' but it also shows the incomplete deployed application apart from deployed.

Comment: you can also view the deployed applications from jboss's admin console

Answer (score 1):

You may have to create a script (shell/groovy etc) to get the list of MBeans (using the command you already have) and then iterate through the results to show only the ones with attribute **State = 3** (using twiddle get option).

Answer (score 0):

Please use this command:-

```
./twiddle.sh query "jboss.web.deployment:*"
```